# Find the top n largest values from a dataframe (or matrix) in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like below:

```
df = data.frame(a = runif(10,0,10),
            b = runif(10,1,10),
            c = runif(10,0,12))
```

How can I find the n largest values from this dataframe?
We can easily find top n from a vector. Is there any good way to find the top n from a dataframe?
  Thanks a lot.

Comment: So the output is a single vector of the 10 largest values from any of the columns?

Comment: please explain what you mean by top n of a dataframe.In R, dataframe is a list of columns that are of different data-types arranged in a tabular structure. So top n, by default doesn't make sense for dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unlist` and convert it into a vector, `sort` them and find top values. So for top 2 values we can do

```
tail(sort(unlist(df, use.names = FALSE)), 2)
#[1] 9.581705 9.591726
```

If it's a matrix you'll not require `unlist`

```
tail(sort(as.matrix(df)), 2)
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1233)
df = data.frame(a = runif(10,0,10),
                b = runif(10,1,10),
                c = runif(10,0,12))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can check for `stack`

```
N=2
sort(stack(df)$values, decreasing=TRUE)[1:N]
[1] 10.884644  9.912067
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tidyr::gather()` and `dplyr::top_n()`.

First gather every column in one column using `gather(key, value)`, and filter top n elements using `top_n()`. For example, top-5.

```
library(tidyverse) # dplyr and tidyr
set.seed(10)
mydf <- 
  data.frame(a = runif(10,0,10),
            b = runif(10,1,10),
            c = runif(10,0,12))
```

In `gather()`, freely specify the name of `key` and `value`.

You should name `wt` of `top_n()` as `value` you have given.

```
mydf %>% 
  gather(key = "key", value = "value") %>% 
  top_n(5, wt = value) %>% 
  arrange(desc(value)) # sort by value
#>   key value
#> 1   c 10.38
#> 2   c 10.06
#> 3   c  9.30
#> 4   c  9.25
#> 5   b  8.53
```

You can get the output of top_n values with *corresponding column names*.

---

However, if you just want only values, you can use `unlist()`.

```
unlist(mydf) %>% # optionally, use.names = FALSE
  sort(decreasing = TRUE) %>% 
  .[1:5]
#>    c1    c7    c3    c9   b10 
#> 10.38 10.06  9.30  9.25  8.53
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're looking for [`slice_max()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/slice.html).

Given, for example, the data below:

```
> df = data.frame(a = runif(5,0,10),
+                 b = runif(5,1,10),
+                 c = runif(5,-1,9))
> df
         a        b           c
1 1.953615 6.663370  6.95084517
2 1.564794 2.376268  1.46826979
3 5.052276 3.609657  0.84467786
4 3.800541 5.506710  5.64018236
5 9.823815 9.158154 -0.03483406
```

We can get the three topmost rows (defined by the parameter `n`) sorted by the column `a`...

```
> slice_max(df, n=3, order_by=a)
         a        b           c
1 9.823815 9.158154 -0.03483406
2 5.052276 3.609657  0.84467786
3 3.800541 5.506710  5.64018236
```

...column `b`...

```
> slice_max(df, n=3, order_by=b)
         a        b           c
1 9.823815 9.158154 -0.03483406
2 1.953615 6.663370  6.95084517
3 3.800541 5.506710  5.64018236
```

...or column `c`:

```
> slice_max(df, n=3, order_by=c)
         a        b        c
1 1.953615 6.663370 6.950845
2 3.800541 5.506710 5.640182
3 1.564794 2.376268 1.468270
```